# How to tell there is another thread trying to hold mutex?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I have an algorithm, efficiency critical, and 90% of time runs in single thread mode. Now we realize there is another 10% use case we need to make it support multi-threading.

The sad part is there is a portion of this algorithm, does require mutex protection in multi-threading case.  This critical section repeats for billions of times, thus it is really a waste of ticks to keep mutex operation in single thread.

Is it possible to make a class "mutex aware" so that we only trigger mutex protection when we detect there is another thread running this class instance?  What is the best practise in c++?

Update: 
Some folks think the problem unclear. My bad. Let me try with more details.

90% of time the system is scanning through large amount of data (imagine it as many data boxes) continuously, and send out stats to other threads, but not much detail. Then some times, if a RPC client gets something interesting, it asks for more information for a particular range of box. Moving between boxes is very expensive, therefore no random access here. At this point, the client algorithm seeks back to get those particular boxes as planned. Now it is the sub-algorithm (i.e. handles ONE SINGLE box) requires mutex here (to maintain pointer status, the boundary handling and many other stuff etc).

Because 90% of time the algorithm has single thread mode, thus I just want it move fast, without acquiring a lock on every box. And when there is a client wants to seek and use the one-box algorithm, this becomes the only situation (and we can only know about it at run-time) that a mutex kicks in.

Comment: Seems like [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/330769/) you can find the answer.

Comment: Without more information about the problem will be hard for anyone to help you. Take a read at https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-concurrency-and-lock-free-programming and check if you can do it as a lock-free code.

Comment: What do you mean with `use case we need to make it support multi-threading`? That the algorithm itself uses multiple threads to solve one task. Or to make your algorithm thread save so that multiple threads can use the same algorithm for different tasks.

Comment: You could create the mutex dynamically only when actually needed, and have the algorithm use the mutex only if it has been created.

Comment: Is it possible for the server to copy the contents of the single box for the client to access it separately?

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to make your code templated on a mutex type, then in the single threaded case pass a fake mutex. Eg something like this:

```
template<typename Mutex>
void foo( Mutex& mutex)
{
   std::unique_lock lock(mutex);
   // Do stuff
}
```

Then you can call with and without a mutex:

```
std::mutex mutex;
foo(mutex);

struct fake_mutex
{
   void lock(){}
   void unlock(){}
};

fake_mutex mutex;
foo(mutex);
```

The compiler should optimise away the fake mutex to very little or even no code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use-case for Read-Copy-Update (RCU) https://lwn.net/Articles/262464/ . RCU was originally designed requiring OS privileges (specifically, disabling interrupts and scheduling), but there is a user-space RCU library URCU https://lwn.net/Articles/573424/ .

RCU is a lock-free paradigm and heavily optimized for the read case. The privileged version of RCU incurs **no** overhead when entering a read-side critical section in some cases.

I'm skeptical that you actually need a mutex and I think you might be able to use RCU instead of a mutex. However, if you wish to keep the mutex you could use an RCU flag as a condition to lock the mutex. This is a little non-standard since generally shared data protected by a mutex should always use the mutex, but it's ok because RCU protection is as good as a mutex.

You will have to read through a lot of material to understand RCU, but here's a crash course explaining the privileged RCU flavor.

To enter a read-side critical section, the CPU disables interrupts (for that CPU only). The CPU can then read a flag, like `if (!locked)`. After completing the read-side critical section, the CPU re-enables interrupts.

If a thread wishes to modify some data, it writes to the flag `locked = true` and propagates the write (via memory barrier). At this point, any new read-side critical sections will see the flag locked and avoid entering the critical section, but we still have to worry about read-side critical sections currently in progress. So the modifying thread schedules itself on every CPU. If another CPU is in a read-side critical section, interrupts on that CPU will be disabled, therefore the modifying thread will be unable to run on that CPU until the read-side critical section is complete. After this locking function returns, the data can be modified, as it is guaranteed exclusive access.

An alternative to RCU is hazard pointers, which is more optimized for the even read/write access case than RCU. Hazard pointers are also lock-free. The idea behind hazard pointers is for a thread to mark the things it is using. I think your case is more suited to RCU, but there are probably more libraries that implement hazard pointers.